# UWP XAML designer doesn't load

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

When I create a new universal application, XAML designer doesn't load and it shows the following exception instead:

[image: An Unhandled has occurred]
Restarting windows, reopening the project or even reinstalling VS didn't solve that.

Comment: Was there anything in the logs that the message refers to?

Comment: The [troubleshooting doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh973484%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may help also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check and install Windows updates, it helped in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling or repairing Visual Studio might help.

Answer (score 0):

In my case uninstalling the App you're developing (Start Menu -> All Apps -> Your App -> Right click -> Uninstall) and rebuilding the solution/re-running the app worked.