# Unable to view designer in UWP app

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am a beginner in UWP app and facing issues in a very initial stage of writing my “Hello world” program.
I am trying to create a new project of type “BlankApp (Universal Windows)”.

[image: New Project]

[image: Blank App (Universal Windows)]

After the new project got created I cant able to see the designer of XAML, its displaying only the XAML script.

In WPF projects the designer is loading properly as expected.

Comment: also post a picture of you what you see after the project is created

Comment: What's your systems' version? Is it Build 10240 or 10586? And what's your  project's target version? You can find the target version in the **Application** tab of your project's **Properties**. If the target version is larger then your system's version, you can set the target version to your system's version or update your system to match the target version. You can have a try and to see if the XAML Designer shows.

Answer (score 0):

I've already answered it here:

[UWP XAML designer doesn't load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35586371/uwp-xaml-designer-doesnt-load/35624142#35624142/)

Try to get the latest Windows update.